# Solve the equations: $\cos\left(z\right)=2+4i, \text{Log}\left(z\right)=\left(1+i\right)\pi, \arctan\left(z\right)=1+i$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, inverse-function

Solve the following equations:

$$ \cos\left(z\right)=2+4i$$
$$  \text{Log}\left(z\right)=\left(1+i\right)\pi$$

$$ \arctan\left(z\right)=1+i$$

---

For the first one we know that $$cos(z)=\cos\left(z\right)=\cos\left(x\right)\cosh\left(y\right)-i\sin\left(x\right)\sinh\left(y\right)=2+4i$$

Which implies $$\cos\left(x\right)\cosh\left(y\right)=2$$
and $$\sin\left(x\right)\sinh\left(y\right)=-4$$

Then how to proceed?

---

For the second one $$\text{Log}\left(z\right)=\ln\left|z\right|+i\text{Arg}(z)=\left(1+i\right)\pi$$
Which implies $$\ln\left|z\right|=\pi$$ and $$\text{Arg}(z)=\pi$$

So the solution to the equation is $z=e^\pi e^{\pi(2k+1)}$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$.

---

For the last one $$\arctan\left(z\right)=\frac{i}{2}\log\left(\frac{i+z}{i-z}\right)=1+i$$

I don't know how to continue

Comment: $\arccos (z)=-i\log\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Using you approach for the first ones
$$\cos\left(x\right)\cosh\left(y\right)=2\tag1$$
$$\sin\left(x\right)\sinh\left(y\right)=-4\tag2$$

$(1)$gives $\cos(x)=2 \,\text{sech}(y)$ and $(2)$ gives $\sin(x)=-4 \,\text{csch}(y)$

$$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=\color{red}{16 \,\text{csch}^2(y)+4 \,\text{sech}^2(y)=1} \tag 3$$

The "red" equation does not show obvious roots and its solution requires numerical methods. Graphing, you would notice that the function
$$f(x)=\log\Big[16 \,\text{csch}^2(y)+4 \,\text{sech}^2(y) \Big]$$ is very linear as soon as $y>1$ and the solution $y=\pm 2.19857$ is very easy to find. Then, reusing $(1)$, $\cos(x)=0.43845$ then $x$ (do not forget the modulo).

Answer (score 0):

The second and third are very easy since $\exp$ and $\tan$ are not multi-valued:

$\text{Log} \ z = (1+i)\pi \implies z = \exp((1+i)\pi)$

Can you take it from here?